# conflict between two extensions

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a problem since I've installed a second extension on my `joomla(2.5)` website.
The console log shows:

> "TypeError: $(...).addEvent is not a function"

linked to the extension `"adminForm"` :

```
$('adminForm_'+pf).addEvent('submit', function(e) {...}
```

Both extensions seems to be using `addEvent()` so it creates the conflict...
When I disable one of the two extension it works fine but I have to use them both.

Is there a way to make them work together without any conflict?

Thank you

Comment: Which template are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easy way is just use the jquery no conflict

You need:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

And replace

```
$('adminForm_'+pf).addEvent('submit', function(e) {...}
```

with

```
jQuery('adminForm_'+pf).addEvent('submit', function(e) {...}
```

You can also see this [extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) that suports no conflict. The idea is replace `$` with `jQuery`. Probably you are having a conflict between libraries (mootools and jquery).

[See more here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)